# How can i require and print an object array beetwen a jsp page and a servlet using JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

How can i print *messages2* into *div class=chat*?

A message is composed by: 
- Id 
- Text

I can't read JSON file which servlet send to me with my JQuery function.
I'm new in JQuery and this script isn't mine but i used it because it works to send messages to servelt.

This is my form where i will take a text from input.
**home.jsp**

```
<form  method="post" id="messageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">     
                <div class="chat">  
                   //where i will print the array 
                </div>

        <div class="send">
            <div class="text-message-container">
                <input type="text" name="testMessage" class="text-message" id="toSend">
                <button type="submit" class="send-message" onclick="addMessage();" ><img src="img/send1.png" class="img-send"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form> 
<script>
function addMessage(){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xhttp.open("POST","messageServlet",true);
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('messageForm'));
xhttp.send(formData);
 }
  else console.log('not working');
} </script>
```

**This is my Servlet:**

```
@WebServlet(name = "messageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/messageServlet"})
@MultipartConfig
public class messageServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String msg = req.getParameter("testMessage");
SessionFactory factory = session.getSessionFactory();
Session s = factory.openSession(); 
Message m = new Message();        
    m.setMessage(msg);
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(m);
    s.getTransaction().commit();

    List<Message> messages2 = s.createQuery("From Message").list();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(messages2);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your home.jsp has a syntax error in the Javascript code:

```
    var myArr = JSON.parse(
```

Everything else looks fine as far as I can see.